# Nginx unit requires using port 80 for initial setting?

Tags: python, nginx-unit

I installed Nginx unit

```
systemctl status unit
● unit.service - NGINX Unit
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/unit.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-09-02 15:33:30 JST; 4min 29s ago
    Process: 2288597 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/unitd $DAEMON_ARGS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 2288600 (unitd)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 2282)
     Memory: 5.6M
     CGroup: /system.slice/unit.service
             ├─2288600 unit: main v1.25.0 [/usr/sbin/unitd]
             ├─2288613 unit: controller
             └─2288614 unit: router

Sep 02 15:33:30 tk2-243-31156 systemd[1]: Starting NGINX Unit...
Sep 02 15:33:30 tk2-243-31156 unitd[2288597]: 2021/09/02 15:33:30 [info] 2288597#2288597 unit started
Sep 02 15:33:30 tk2-243-31156 systemd[1]: Started NGINX Unit.
```

Now,I try to first test

```
sudo curl --unix-socket /var/run/unit/control.sock http://localhost/
```

However it returns curl: `(7) Couldn't connect to server`

I guess on this service `apache` works ,so port 80 is used....

Is there any work around??

Comment: Configure nginx to run on a different port?

Comment: Yes I want to do so , but it requires to access http://localhost to change setting.

Comment: You are on a localhost, so that is not a problem. Do you have root or administrative (sudo) access at least? (It seems so from the curl command.)

Comment: hey @whitebear still open? happy to assist.